# How to replace subscript symbols

Tags: replacement

I have an expression with subscripted variables. I would like to replace all those terms with other symbols. For example,

$P_1 + P_2^3 \rightarrow P1 + P2^3$

I used the following code but it doesn't work

```
X = Subscript[P, 1] + Subscript[P, 3]^2 - I*Subscript[P, 5]
X /. {Subscript[P, n_] -> Pn}
```

If I replace `Subscript[P, n_]` with `P[n]` then it works (e.g. $P_1$ will be replaced with `P[1]`) but I don't want the bracket. I want `P1` instead. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `Pn` use `Symbol["P"<>ToString[n]]`

Answer (score 4):

```
X /. Subscript[x_, y_] :> Symbol[StringJoin@(ToString /@ {x, y})]
```