# Calling variables with use of numbers in their names

Tags: variable-definitions

I have got few huge matrices named by ascending numbers, e.g. `x1, x2, x3,...` and I need to do the same operation with all of them - to multiply their components, obtain the absolute value etc. As I am beginner with *Mathematica* I usually copy the expression and rewrite indexes as `x1 -> x2`, but this is very lengthy. I would like to have only one expression with something like `xX`, where I just change `X` by index of particular matrix.

Comment: related: [33184](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33184/5478)

Answer (score 2):

```
f @ Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[10]
```

> ```
> {f[x1], f[x2], f[x3], f[x4], f[x5], f[x6], f[x7], f[x8], f[x9], f[x10]}
> ```

---

e.g.

```
x1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 5}];
x2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 5}];

Composition[
  Abs,
  Tr,
  Flatten,
  Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] &

  ] /@ Range[2]
```

Answer (score -1):

Less sophisticated approach.  The ?? at the end shows that Mathematica knows about these eight symbols.  If I click on the "light blue" A1 in the Global` symbol table that appears in my notebook after entering ??Global`A*, the 16 elements of A1 are shown as a list of lists.

```
    In[1]:= Table[Symbol["A" <> ToString[i]], {i, 8}]

    Out[1]= {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8}

    (* All of the symbols in the above list can be set to have numerical values *)

    (* and manipulated as usual.  For example: *)

    In[2]:= A1 = RandomReal[{-10.0, 10.0}, {4, 4}]

    Out[2]= {{-5.5598, 9.8372, -0.700913, 2.89629}, 
             {-6.42822, 1.26682, -7.52955, 3.2075},
             {0.28862, -7.03238, 0.366672, 9.61496}, 
             {6.60329, -8.92156, -8.83749, -7.38917}}

    In[3]:= A1.Inverse[A1] // Chop

    Out[3]= {{1., 0, 0, 0}, 
             {0, 1., 0, 0}, 
             {0, 0, 1., 0},
             {0, 0, 0, 1.}}

    In[4]:= ?? Global`A*

        Global`
        A1   A2   A3   A4   A5   A6   A7   A8
```

But I guess I'm not answering your question.  Sorry.

Comment: Dear user15996, we are very glad you found the site. Thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately I can't see how this answers the question.